# How can I round to next floor 0.5 in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I would like to round Double variables to the next lower 0.5 value.
For instance

> 12.03 -> 12

> 12.44 -> 12

> 12.56 -> 12.5

> 12.99 -> 12.5

There should be an elegant easy Kotlin like way?

Comment: Note that, due to [the way floating-point values work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), the result will probably not be _exactly_ what you expect…  If you need an exact value, use another format (such as `BigDecimal`, or scaled integers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiply by 2, take the `floor`, then divide by 2 again.

There doesn't seem to be a built-in way, but you can always write it yourself:

```
fun Double.roundDownToMultipleOf(base: Double): Double = base * floor(this / base)
```

Use as `12.56.roundDownToMultipleOf(0.5)`.

Comment: Works perfect thanks. I was looking for smt like this. How could I leave 12.5 but print 12.0 as 12 straight?

Comment: @PavelPipovic Not so easy anymore but you could make your own method: `fun Double.format() = if (this == toInt().toDouble()) toInt().toString() else toString()` which you then can use like `12.5.format()` or like `12.0.format()` which will return `12.5` resp. `12`